nftables: MAC address bitwise match
I want to mark tcp/udp packets which have a source MAC address with locally administered bit.
I tried the following 4 nftables rules, the syntax is ok but nothing happens.
How to match MAC addresses by bitwise operation ?
meta oifname enp4s0 ether saddr & 0f:00:00:00:00:00 == 02:00:00:00:00:00 meta l4proto {tcp, udp} ct mark set 0x0001
meta oifname enp4s0 ether saddr & 0f:00:00:00:00:00 == 06:00:00:00:00:00 meta l4proto {tcp, udp} ct mark set 0x0001
meta oifname enp4s0 ether saddr & 0f:00:00:00:00:00 == 0a:00:00:00:00:00 meta l4proto {tcp, udp} ct mark set 0x0001
meta oifname enp4s0 ether saddr & 0f:00:00:00:00:00 == 0e:00:00:00:00:00 meta l4proto {tcp, udp} ct mark set 0x0001

